# How to get access to every element of the 2d array and than replace them?

Tags: python

```
arr = [['.' for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]

for line, i in enumerate(arr):
    for column, j in enumerate(i):
        print(j, 'at column', column+1, 'line', line+1) # we can know which  
                                                        # postition takes 
                                                        # every element
```

How out of loop to check if coordinate is different with another coordinate.

## What I want to get in final:

*pseudocode:*

```
#arr[x][y]
arr[1][0] = 'new'
if arr[1][4] - arr[1][0] == 4: # i.e. coord are different by `y` on 4 pos 
    arr[1][4] = 'new'`

               # Before || After
[[' ', 'new', ' ', ' '],||  [[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],   ||   [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],   ||   [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],   ||   [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]   ||   [' ', 'new', ' ', ' ']]
```

## OR

```
#arr[x][y]
arr[0][0] = 'new'
if arr[3][0] - arr[0][0] == 3: # i.e. coord are different by `x` on 3 pos 
    arr[3][0] = 'new'`

               # Before || After
[['new', ' ', ' ', ' '],||  [[' ', ' ', ' ', 'new'],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],   ||   [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],   ||   [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],   ||   [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]   ||   [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

Necessarily need to know which list in main list takes position, but how it does outside of loop without numpy, using native python?

Comment: Could you please reformulate your question? Do you want new to be written in every field except for the location it was written before?

Comment: @SebastianWalla, No, I just want to change position `new` element in 2d array, previously checking the possible movement. It's hard because I can't get how to appropriate every cell coordinate `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: How out of loop to check if coordinate is different with another coordinate.

Define the coordinate's using `tuple`, then compare the `tuples`:

```
RC = (1,4)
RC2 = (1,0)

if RC == RC2:
    print('Equal')
else:
    print('Different')
```

Type `list` is 0 Based
You have a list of lists.

RC Coordinate System, the same as with Excel
R == index of `list` in `list` == y == Row
C == index inside a `list` == x == Column

```
        A    B    C    D
C =>     0    1    2    3
    ----------------------
R:0 | [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
R:1 | [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3]
R:2 | [2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3]
R:3 | [3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3]
```

---

Use the opposite

```
#arr[y][x]
```

The first index=y is the index of a `list` in `arr`, alias **row**.
The second index=x is the index inside the `list` selected with `y`, alias **column**.

Comment: Don't get it, can you explain? How it helps?

Comment: @This4fun: Updated my AnswerRead [What should I do when someone answers my question?]
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers